# TFS 2010: Service Unavailable 503

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I've been trying to solve this problem for about a week now.  I posted this question on Microsoft website and only received one reply, which did not solve my issue. The following is a combination of my posts on Microsoft website.

I installed and configured TFS 2010 on Window 7 PC 64-bit. When I navigate to http://localhost:8080/tfs in my browser, I get

> Service Unavailable – HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Any help to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Based on previous reading, I have done much work to figure this out.  Following are the steps I have gone through to solve this issues.  The list is fairly long, but I want to make sure all the information that may be pertinent to solving this problem is available.

- I have uninstalled and reinstalled TFS many times
- The application pool "Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool" is running
- The application pool "Microsoft Team Foundation Server Web Access Application Pool" is running
- Other website in IIS that point to the "ASP.NET v4.0" app pool seem to run fine.
- If I point my other sites to "Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool" they 
  seems to run fine
- The Windows user "TFS" is in the following rolls: Administrator, IIS_IUSRS, - TFS_APPTIER_SERVICE_WPG, Users
- I'm able to run SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) as the user "TFS" and access the databases "Tfs_Configuration" and "Tfs_DefaultCollection"
- I have confirm the account for "TFS" is not disabled or expired
- For IIS application "Team Foundation Server", I Configured "Failed Request Tracing Rules" to log status codes 401.3-999
- After IIS Reset and browser refresh, no files in the "FailedReqLogFiles" directory
- No log information in IIS Logs
- In Team Foundation Server Administration Console, I can change account info(Update Password, Change Account, Reapply Account).
- In Team Foundation Server Administration Console, when I try to changing Group Membership or Administer Security I get the error "Team Foundation services are not available from server http://localhost:8080/tfs.  Technical information (for administrator): HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable"
- In Event Viewer, I do not see anything that may be of value
  In Sql Server Configuration Manager, confirmed "SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration - (32bit)", "SQL Server Network Configuration", and "SQL Native Client 10 Configuration" all have the following protocols enabled (Shared Memory, TCP/IP, and Named Pipes"
- In IE confirmed that that Proxy server is not enable.

I installed Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools.  The following are the Critical Issues returned by the tool

- Accessing "AuthorizationService" Web service at "/DefaultCollection/Services/v3.0/AuthorizationService3.asmx" failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- Accessing "BuildService" Web service at "/DefaultCollection/Build/v3.0/BuildService.asmx" failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- The Web service call "CommonStructureService.ListAllProjects" at "/Services/v1.0/CommonStructureService.asmx" failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."
- Accessing "GroupSecurityService" Web service at "/DefaultCollection/Services/v1.0/GroupSecurityService.asmx" failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- Accessing "IdentityManagementService" Web service at "/DefaultCollection/Services/v3.0/IdentityManagementService.asmx" failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- The Web service call "Integration Services ProcessTemplate.GetTemplateName" at http://MyServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Services/v1.0/ProcessTemplate.asmx failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- Accessing "LabService" Web service at "/DefaultCollection/Lab/v3.0/LabService.asmx" failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- The Web service call "ProcessTemplate.TemplateHeaders" at "/Services/v1.0/ProcessTemplate.asmx" failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."
- Accessing "Repository" Web service at "/DefaultCollection/VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx" failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- Accessing "SecurityService" Web service at "/DefaultCollection/Services/v3.0/SecurityService.asmx" failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- The Web service call "TeamProjectCollection.GetDefaultCollectionId" at http://MyServer:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/TeamProjectCollectionService.asmx failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- The Web service call "VersionControl.Administration.QueryRepositoryInformation" at http://MyServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/VersionControl/v1.0/administration.asmx failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- The Web service call "VersionControl.Administration.QueryRepositoryInformation" at http://MyServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/VersionControl/v1.0/administration.asmx failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".
- The Web service call "ConfigurationSettings.ServiceGetWorkitemTrackingVersion" at http://MyServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/ConfigurationSettingsService.asmx failed. Error message: "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.".

The follow are additional issues that were not critical:

- SharePoint Products is not installed or integrated with Team Foundation Server.
- Team Foundation Server is not configured to use the data warehouse.
- Team Foundation Server is not configured to use Report Manager.
- Results for rules that require access to Team Foundation Build cannot be included in the report.
- Cannot validate the configuration of Visual Studio Lab Management. Results for rules that check the health of Visual Studio Lab Management will not be included in the report.
- Paged pool memory on MyServer is over the warning threshold of 180 MB. This may not be a problem if a backup is currently in progress. Current value: 490 MB.

The follow are Information Items:

- Computer: MyServer. Manufacturer: System manufacturer. Model: System Product Name.
- The application tier connected to Team Foundation Server at 12/2/2010 9:09:49 PM.
- The connection string in config file c:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web ervices\Web.config on MyServer is: Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=Tfs_Configuration;Integrated Security=True;.
- The connection string stored in the Team Foundation Server registry is: Data Source=MyServer;Initial atalog=Tfs_Configuration;Integrated Security=True.
- Logical disk C: on MyServer is 500 GB in size.
- No Sharepoint Site is configured for this Team Project Collection "DefaultCollection".
- No Sharepoint Site is configured for this Team Project Collection "DefaultCollection".
- The MyServer is running the 64-bit version of Windows.
- The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service on MyServer is configured to run as user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.
- The account Identity for the Team Foundation Server application pool on MyServer is MyServer\TFS. This is the same as the Team Foundation Server service account.
  The Team Foundation Server Product Version is 10.0.30319.317
- The Team Foundation Server Service Level is Tfs2010.RTM.KB2135068.P#3.
- The MyServer has 1 processor(s) installed.
- The MyServer has 6134 MB of memory installed.
- Volume C:\ on MyServer is a mount point.

I started up a Virtual Machine with Windows 7.  Installed and configured TFS.  Everything seems to work fine on the Virtual Machine.  With an environment working, I started to compare differences between the two.

Here are some of the differences I found between the two environments:

- My primary computer is 64-bit and the Virtual Machine is 32-bit.
- On my primary computer, IIS "Team Foundation Server Website" has a "aspnet_client" directory.  On the virtual machine, this directory does not exist
- On my primary computer, in IIS Manager for "Team Foundation Server" the section ASP.NET are the same on both my primary computer and virtual machine.
- On my primary computer, IIS Manager IIS Section has these additional feature that the virtual machine does not include (ASP, Authorization Rules, CGI, IP Address and Domains, and WebDav Authorization)
- On my primary computer, IIS Application Pool setting has a property call "Enabled 32-Bit Application".  This was set to false and I changed it to true.  Understandably this feature is not available on the virtual machine.

Thanks.

Comment: If you try to deploy a web application and access it on your Win 7 machine, are you able to hit that, or do you also get a 503?  It sounds like an IIS issue more than anything else.

Comment: Definitely sounds like and IIS problem.  What do you see in the Httperr.log file located in %Systemroot%\System32\LogFiles?  It may have more information.  Also, are there any Antivirus programs running on your machine?

Comment: You can try installing SP1 beta to see if that fixes up anything: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d4f5a430-919b-46ee-bab6-ba804402df21&displaylang=en

Comment: in my case the iis application pool was disabled. i noticed after checking httperr.log, so thanks richard. but why should an application pool disable itself over night? strange things happening..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My application pool had been stopped as well and when I looked into why or how, I discovered that it was running under a domain account of one of our admins who initially installed TFS (months ago).

B/C of a corporate domain policy, he was forced to recently enter a new password for his account. Then after business hours last night, an update was applied to the IIS server on which TFS runs, and the update required a reboot. B/C the password of the identity under which the app pool runs had changed, IIS could not restart the pool, as the identity was still set to the original domain account and password.

Once I had the admin enter his new password with the app pool's identity, the pool would restart. However, b/c corporate enforces password expiration like every 90 days, I ultimately changed the identity to local system account in order to avoid this problem in the future (choosing local system may not be the best choice).

Answer (score 7):

- `Start` -> `Administrative Tools` -> `IIS`
- `{Server name}` -> `Application Pools`
- *Right Click* on `Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool` -> `Advanced Settings`
- `Identity` -> `Choose Custom Account` -> *Click* `Set` -> Enter the username and password of the *system admin*
- **Stop** then **Start** `Microsoft Team Foundation Server Message Queue Application Pool`
- **Stop** then **Start** `Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool`
  [image]

Answer (score 5):

I got this error as well. In the application pool there is a TFS App Pool that was stopped. Once this was started again the 503 error stopped occuring

Answer (score 2):

I never got it to work.  I created a VM and installed Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2010 and everything seem to work good.  To conclude, I'm not sure what was wrong, but if I install it on a fresh server everything works fine

Comment: Sometimes it the fastest way to get out of a mess

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing you must do is to ensure that the application pool is running.

Comment: Yep, first thing I checked too, and that was it.  May have a deeper reason, like our domain controller changing something or fiddling with TFS security a few days prior, but anyway, good advice to check.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem. Our TFS server is not part of a domain. I noticed that the HTTP log file seemed to list IPv6 addresses at times and at other times IPv4.

I turned off IPv6 and we were able to once again connect to TFS.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck Limit connection on IIS to solve this problem.

[Limiting Connections (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b2b550de-f655-4fb6-9bed-dfc9583b6700.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

In my case... (my problems aren't related to how TFS is setup but accessed from a workstation)

I work for a large bank and have a sophisticated firewall/proxy - suffice it to say I have had to play with clicking various options to properly connect to our TFS ***AND*** connect to the Internet (to download Visual Studio extensions). I fix my error under the proxy settings in IE under OPTIONS | Connections | LAN Settings...

Comment: Any idea what settings you changed to allow it to work?  I'm unable to use the connection over a shared VPN connection but when the VPN client is running directly on my machine it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some 503 errors from TFS myself, if my memory serves correctly (I can't test much as my test server is currently down) I had some issues with the versions of ASP.NET the TFS website was configured to use.

Check that ASP.NET is configured to use version 4.0 in IIS (right click the site > Properties > ASP.NET).  Also make sure that no other non TFS sites are in the same application pool as your TFS site (actually a virtual directory in your TFS site) and configured separately (they don't seem to play well together!).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today.
Resolution is start installation distrib of TFS and repair product
(in my way i re-install only tfs 2010 service pack 1).

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my team foundation services from application pool through inetmgr and found my services was not running.i started it and now i am able to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

After installing several times I got it working with installing SQL Server 2008 R2 (Developer) instead of using SQLExpress.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Application Tier in TFS Administration Console and change account; it may fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I very recently ran into a similar issue. One of our tools sporadically failed when attempting to contact our TFS resource. Comparing the machines in our TFS VIP, only one machine had IIS errors, namely (truncated): 503 8080 QueueFull Microsoft+Team+Foundation+Server+Application+Pool. A quick comparison of app pool settings showed that the good machine had a queue length of 1000, the bad had only 10. 1000 might be excessive, but 10 was apparently too small. I am yet to verify that changing queue length from 10 to 1000 fixed my issue. Hopefully I remember to complete my post! Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

If the TFS server name is longer than 15 characters it could be an issue with the netbios name being different than the servername. In our case the AppFabric Service was crashing, and we had to use the following to fix the Cache Host name:

http://www.andrewjbillings.com/long-server-name-causing-app-fabric-service-to-crash/

This resolved the `TF24668: The following team project collection is stopped` errors that we were getting, along with some `TF400732: The request has been canceled.` and `TF246066: Team Foundation Server is offline.` error messages

Answer (score 0):

I have TFS installed on my local machine and TFS is running under custom account.

I solved 503 error by setting the App Pool credentials again (Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool and Microsoft Team Foundation Server Message Queue Application Pool)

Answer (score 0):

Another, pretty special reason could be, that you set "Logon as a batch job" in AD explicitly. If you do not specify this setting it defaults to "Administrators;Backup Operators". If you overwrite it e. g. to allow a custom account to schedule a task you must make to not forget adding the default values. Else exactly this problem 503 Service unavailable and a stopped app pool appears.