# Error 500 when trying to connect to Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

I have installed and configured Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 3 in one of our server a few weeks ago.

All was going well until the pc unexpectedly was shut down due to electrical problem. After turning on again we now get:

> Error 500 internal server error.

Tried to access the web server and got the HTTP Error

> 403.14 - Forbidden.

TFS administration console seems fine. I'm not sure where to look next. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of TFS?

Comment: @DanielMann sorry I thought I mentioned it. Added 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please check your **Event View** on your TFS server machine to see if there are more detail info or error message for trouble shooting.

For `Error 500 internal server error.`  There's no much value for now.

For `403.14-Forbidden` error, this may related to IIS server. Suggest you try to restart the TFS applicaton on IIS. And also [clean all cache of TFS server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), located at`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache`

To narrow down the issue, you could also use Visual Studio to connect TFS server. If this works, suggest you to clear IE cache and try again.

Besides, since the PC unexpectedly shut down, please also check if the related TFS service started properly, if not manually start them.

Comment: Went to Administrative Tools > Event Viewer > Application and Services Logs and got 0 events. Already tried to restart the IIS application. Turned on directory browsing and error no longer shows but just shows me the directory for inetpub. Connecting using visual studio gives me the same generic error code 500....feel stuck because of this

Comment: @TheProvost If so, do you have any other account or machine? Suggest you use another account or client machine to connect  TFS server see if it works. By the way, do you have any anti-virus software running on your machine, try to turn it off temporary. Also turn off the firewall. This will indicate if it's a client issue or sever side issue.

Comment: Anti virus is turned off. Firewall is turned off as well. Same error message. Tried another account and same issue appears

Comment: @TheProvost  Have you clear  the TFS server cache in your machine? According to your update, this should be a server side issue. Please take a look at the similar question here and give a try with some, especially Alla's reply. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24836280/5391065 .  Another speculation: Please make sure that your SQL instance is running.

Comment: Yes cleared the cache and same issue happens. I cleared the server cache as well in TFSData folder. For the application pool error yes this was the first thing I checked. It was stopped when I check it but was able to turn it on by restarting and changing the password for the AD account used by iis

Comment: @TheProvost Have no idea why the issue still exists and lacking of related error message. For Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (TFS) to operate correctly, all required services, application pools, and Web sites must be running on the appropriate server. In single-server deployments, each component must run on the server that runs TFS. You could go through and check each of this, related tutorial [Stop and start services, application pools, and websites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/stop-start-stuff).

Comment: @TheProvost The application pool stopped when server unexpectedly shut down is the only pointcut for now. Guess the issue is still related to this area. Also check the Configuration logs in TFS administration console if there are related info. If everything has tried and nothing worked. Even though it's not a good suggestion, but you may have to reinstall the TFS Application Tire(Back up the database first). This should do the trick.

Comment: Is re-installing and repair different? because I already tried repairing and it didn't work. Do you mean uninstalling then installing it again? this is just a test server so I can do that if that's what it takes

Comment: We do also have a prod server though....and re-installing isn't really an option there. Basically I'm just asking this question if ever this happened to our prod server as well.

Comment: @TheProvost Not repair, just re-install. Another advice is  **Enable the Directory Browsing feature in IIS** according to error info `403.14 - Forbidden.` https://support.microsoft.com/km-kh/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage

Comment: @TheProvost Besides, don't be worry about the prod server. If you also got the same error there,  each server machine is different, first try the advice above.  If every solution not worked, you could connect  our support team. https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-support/  They will help you collect logs and even remote to the server machine do the troubleshooting to figure out the issue.

Comment: As I said earlier I already tried Enable the directory browsing. That just does what it says, it shows me what inside the web directory. So not really the solution that we are after.

Comment: Hmm ok would try to re-install. I'm assuming the custom process template configuration we did is saved in the database right? so no settings will change?

Comment: @TheProvost Sorry, too many comments, didn't noticed you already said it. Yes, the custom process template configuration saved in the database, when you re-install just select the exist database. However if you still have fears then you could download/export the customize wit locally by using [TFS Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) as a backup.

Comment: Hi @TheProvost Any update on this issue, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs across this issue, we had the same problem and it turned out to be the system time on our TFS SQL Server had gotten out of sync.  It was off by a number of hours.  When I reset the time to be correct, I was able to connect to the TFS instance again without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was migrating from TFS 2013 to AzureDevops Server 2020 using XAML Build. The error on Event Viewer from Application Tier Server was "*Exception Message: The protocol binding '*:443:*.domain.com.br' is not valid for 'https'.  This might be because the port number is out of range. (type UriFormatException)*". I adjusted on IIS the https bindings to accept requests from IP Server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTLX7.png)